# Rails 4.1 jquery slideToggle inside coffee script works only in 1 direction but not the other

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I am attempting to write a small amount of jquery inside of the default rails generated coffee script files (my way of slowly migrating to using that). My code is simple and does the following.

1. Hide a search form
2. Show the search form when the search link is clicked
3. Hide the search form when the search link is clicked again

1 and 2 work without any issue but 3 does not. It's as if jquery unloaded once the link to toggle the form is clicked. I was wondering if anyone can help me understand what I might have over looked.

My coffee scripts is as follows:

```
$('#search_form').hide()
$('#search_link').click ->
  $('#search_form').slideToggle()
```

I also verified that I have this same problem if I use jquery as is:

```
$('#search_form').hide();
$('#search_link').click(function(){
   $('#search_form').slideToggle();
});
```

My div that surrounds the form is as follows:

```
<div id='search_form'>
  ...
</div>
<a href="#" id='search_link'>Search</a>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks good to me: http://jsfiddle.net/dtengeri/BrNv4/ Do you have any errors on your javascript console?

Comment: Actually this problem seems to be a bit bigger. It looks like anything I try to run using jquery causes jquery to unload. If I switch out the code and put in an alert instead of a slideToggle(), the alert pops up and and once I hit ok, the form displays even though it should still be hidden.

Comment: I found the issue. I am using jquery-turbolinks in my rails application and I didn't specify it correctly. I had //= require turbolinks instead of //= require jquery.turbolinks.